# Shouldn't we name the caret tag "r-caret" for consistency with SO?

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

Shouldn't we name the caret tag [r-caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/r-caret) for consistency with SO?

(The main reason is compatibility. Another minor reason is we frequently migrate questions CV <-> SO. So if you migrate SO->CV, the tag is instantly wrong. This creates constant need for tag cleanup and mistagging.)

(The reason for the SO tag naming is **disambiguation**, not a violation of why we don't have language-specific tags.
It is to disambiguate on SO from posts about 'caret', referring to an onscreen text-cursor ; and they use 'punctuation' for the operator/punctuation symbol.
This is also the reason that SO tag can't and shouldn't change.
So all that is not up for discussion, and the SO-side usage won't change.)

Comment: This is probably something that should be handled on SO side, IMO. Are there many packages that are tagged with `r-`? I didn't find `r-ggplot` or `r-Hmisc`, and I believe SO users use two distinct tags, e.g. `r` + `ggplot2`. (Note that there is a `python-ggplot` tag, but I guess this is because this [Python library](http://ggplot.yhathq.com) was inspired by the corresponding R package.)

Comment: No it *isn't* something that can be handled on SO side, and if you'd just clicked through to the definition of r-caret you'd see why it won't and shouldn't change. Yes it's rare to be obligated to call a package 'lang-package' instead of just 'package'. Note that the SO tag is 'r-caret' for disambiguation (thus you still tag both: r r-caret), not to break the convention of not making lang-specific tags.

Comment: @user777 ok if you want to post that as an answer. Just given that there is very frequent migration to/from SO<->CV, it instantly breaks the tag. It helps create constant need for tag cleanup and mistagging.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @chl. SO has a particular convention with its tags, just as CV does. Both are designed to suit different needs, so there's no reason to expect them to coincide. Matching SO convention in this area would break with the package-only convention that exists on CV, so this tag would be a peculiarity among tags. CV doesn't have the ambiguity problem with caret-as-text-character, meaning that there's no ambiguity on our side. This is exclusively an SO problem.

Comment: Uhuh. a) I never suggested match *every* SO tag, only this one because it's commonly migrated b) The reason for the SO tag naming is disambiguation, not a violation of language-specific tags. '[tag:r-caret] is already a peculiarity on SO